# list of frequencies in time to signal in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signals

I'm trying to make (audio) signal from single tone, frequency, which changes over time.

I have tone as 1d numpy array:
freq = [100, 102, 103, 100, 115, 113, ..., 430]

Every value correspondent no N (e.g. 100) samples. I know how to make sure it matches every pattern (N=1). (it can grow and fall at the during of the time)

Now I need this frequency 'curve' convert to sinusoid signal.

I know about [scipy.signal.sweep_poly](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/FrequencySweptDemo.html#Sweep-Poly) (and similar) functions, but i can't describe frequency as polynom.

Please, can you help me, how can I generate signal from frequency list?

Thank you so much!

Comment: If you know how to do `N=1` can't you just apply that solution to `freq=np.repeat(freq, N)`?

Comment: @PaulPanzer Yes, this I know. I need to generate sinusoid signal (as audio signal) with changing frequency in time.

Comment: The frequency is the derivative of the phase. If the frequency changes over time you need to compute the current phase as the integral over the frequency. This is what @PaulPanzer discretly approximates with `cumsum` in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand 100% what you want but how about:

```
freqs = np.random.uniform(100, 400, (20,))
times = np.cumsum(np.random.uniform(0.01, 0.02, (20,)))
# or np.arange(20) / sample_freq if evenly sampled
grid, dt = np.linspace(0, times[-1], 10000, retstep=True)
signal = np.sin(2*np.pi*dt*np.cumsum(np.interp(grid, times, freqs)))
```

This uses linear interpolation between the sampled time points. Other methods are available in `scipy.interpolate`

Comment: This is exactly what i need. Thanks @Paul Panzer!